# Complexity of fractional knapsack problem

Tags: data-structures, greedy-algorithms, knapsack-problems

I am bit confused while reading a standard textbook of my curriculum, where it is mention time complexity for knapsack problem is O(nlogn), and rationale they provided is we need O(n) to calculate (value/weight) value for each weight provided and next we need to sort it using O(nlogn) using any standard sorting algorithm.**(My question here is why cant we use Radix sort or Counting Sort for sorting it to get linear time complexity)**. So that we can get overall complexity as linear time O(n).

Thankyou for sharing your wisdom :)

Comment: Radix sort and counting sort don't work for the general case.

Comment: In [CLRS, 3rd edition](https://sd.blackball.lv/library/Introduction_to_Algorithms_Third_Edition_(2009).pdf), section 8.1 (page 191), you can find $\Omega(n \log n)$ lower bound on sorting. Counting and radix sort make additional assumptions, which help to circumvent the lower bound.

Comment: Hi @Dmitry can you please ellaborate more on your point that counting/radix sort make additional assumptions? Thankyou for your reply.!

Comment: @NirajJain, check section "Counting sort" of the book I shaed